# Ending post request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post, express

Simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer I need. I need to end a POST request without sending back the page html as required in res.end(...); or res.send(...).

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

And this is my request handler in node (I am using exppress):

```
app.post( '/' , function( req, res ) {
if(req.body.hasOwnProperty('username') && req.body.hasOwnProperty('password')){
    console.log("Login requested",req.body.username);
    var minute = 120 * 1000;
    var userid =  UUID();
    res.cookie('user', userid, { maxAge: minute,signed: true});
    // I need to end it here
}
});
```

If I do only res.end(); it shows a blank page on the client, I don't want it doing anything. res.send("info"); once again rewrites whole page with the "info". How do I prevent this? Also I need to send back information, whether the login was succesful or not. If I don't return anything, the page is just stuck on loading.. Anybody ever ecountered such problem or can see any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `res.send()` with a message as you suggested to show that it has ended. Or what I do is, assuming this form is in a jade file (let's call it `index.jade`), I set up a message as a parameter.

So do something like

```
res.render("index", 
            { 
                isLoggedIn: false
            }
        );
```

On the jade layout, you can just check for these variables and display the relevant messages on refresh. So your form would look like the following `index.jade` file:

```
if isLoggedIn
  p Yay!
else
  p Login failed
  form(method="post")
    input(type="text" name="username")
    input(type="password" name="password")
    input(type="submit" value="Login")
```

That is fully utilising the power of Express and Jade. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Both make the page go blank, I don't know if it's relevant, but the page is generated using javascript.

Comment: I am actually using pure javascript to generate the index file (like createElement("div")..), anyway to access the isLoggedIn variable from there?

Also I will have a look into jade as it looks real nice. Thanks for your help so far! :)

Comment: I highly recommend using Jade with express. It is a perfect fit! If you need any guiding links I will be happy to help. Also, if this answer helps you, please mark it as correct :)